# Is it possible to tell when a C++ file is a primary source file?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to determine whether a source file is being preprocessed due to an `#include` statement vs. being preprocessed due to it being a primary source file passed to the compiler?

Basically, I want to be able to write something like the following:

```
// foo.x:
#if COMPILING_FOO_MODULE
/* FOO code that's only visible when compiling foo.x module */
#endif
/* FOO code that's visible when compiling foo.x module or included in other modules */

// bar.cpp:
#include "foo.x"
...
```

When preprocessing `foo.x`, I want both sections of code to be passed on to the compiler, but when preprocessing `bar.cpp`, I only want the second section to be used:

```
// foo.x.preprocessed:
/* FOO code that's only visible when compiling foo.x module */
/* FOO code that's visible when compiling foo.x module or included in other modules */

// bar.cpp.preprocessed:
/* FOO code that's visible when compiling foo.x module or included in other modules */
...
```

I realize I could easily accomplish this by adding `#define COMPILING_FOO_MODULE 0` just before the `#include`, but my goal is to avoid requiring any other code besides the `#include` to be added to the `bar.cpp` file.

Including both [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) since I assume the answer is the same for both.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I understand that having a separate `.h` and `.cpp` file exactly solves this problem, and in almost all cases that's the right thing to do.  But for various reasons I only want one source file that can be used as both the main module source file and the header file for other modules.

Comment: I think you can make use of `#ifdef` and `#else`in your header file and have the definition `#define` in your source file where you include this header file.

Comment: Can't you just `#define HIDE_THE_FIRST_PART` at the top of `bar.cpp` before `#include "foo.x"` and then `ifdef` the part you don't want to see away in `foo.x`?

Comment: How about passing -DCOMPILING_FOO_MODULE=1 into the build just for foo.x? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: There is no **portable** way.  Some specific compilers will provide non-portable ways, like in @agamagarwal's answer

Comment: The error you are trying to solve is likely, that symbols are multiply defined. C++ has the `inline` keyword to prevent just that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do exactly what you want. Try this out:

foo.c

```
#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0
/* FOO code that's only visible when compiling foo.x module */
#endif
/* FOO code that's visible when compiling foo.x module or included in other modules */
```

bar.c

```
#include <foo.c>
//other lines of code
```

Note that the macro *__INCLUDE_LEVEL__* is predefined. It represents the depth of nesting in the include files.

I hope this helps.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for but unfortunately I'm using the Visual Studio compiler and this seems to be GCC-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is traditionally done is to split `foo.x` into two files: `foo.h` and `foo.c` (or `foo.cpp`).

`foo.h` contains *"FOO code that's visible when compiling foo.x module or included in other modules"* and `foo.c` / `foo.cpp` contains *"FOO code that's only visible when compiling foo.x module"*.

Inside `foo.c` / `foo.cpp` you `#include "foo.h"` so that it has both sets of code, and `bar.cpp` also has `#include "foo.h"`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly what led me to this problem in the first place - I'm trying to avoid the need for two separate files.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
#define COMPILING_FOO_MODULE 0
```

in the files which aren't `foo.cpp`, use

```
#define COMPILING_FOO_MODULE 1
```

in `foo.cpp` and nothing in other compilation units.

`#if` works fine with undefined macros, and treats them as zero.

Comment: There is no `foo.cpp`, it's just `foo.x` which is both used as the module's main source file *and* `#include`d by other modules.

Comment: @MooseBoys: Well, pass `-DCOMPILING_FOO_MODULE` when compiling foo as a separate module.  Or, make a `foo.cpp` with just `#define COMPILING_FOO_MODULE 1` followed by `#include "foo.x"`